# How to add new items under category

Tags: virtocommerce

I have create a new category

[image]

that is showing

[image]

but it I add new item under this category this not showing

[image]

[image]

how I can show the new item.

Answer (score 0):

Rebuilding index should help in most cases. Browse -> Catalog, "Rebuild index" at the toolbar of Catalog blade.

Also please check that your category/product has SEO URL.

Comment: @atiksarker I've updated answer. Please check SEO URL of your new product.

Comment: ok i will check that because when i create i didn't mention the SEO.